# How to get Password AutoFill to work with ASWebAuthenticationSession?

Tags: ios, swift, autofill, aswebauthenticationsession

I have a sample HTML form that follows the [password auto-fill requirements](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_an_html_input_element). When navigating to the web page without the app, using the built-in Safari app, the native Password AutoFill dialogs for the login and signup forms correctly show:

[image]

However, when viewed within the app, the same flow does not trigger the dialog in neither the login or signup submission. It simply dismisses the login/signup screen without any error.

This is how my view controller looks like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func didTapLoginButton() {
        let session = ASWebAuthenticationSession(
            url: URL(string: "https://example.com/login.html")!,
            callbackURLScheme: "customscheme") {
                print($0, $1)
        }

        session.prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession = true
        session.presentationContextProvider = self
        session.start()
    }
}

extension ViewController: ASWebAuthenticationPresentationContextProviding {

    func presentationAnchor(for session: ASWebAuthenticationSession) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
        view.window!
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make the Password AutoFill to work with the mobile app via `ASWebAuthenticationSession`? I also tried `SFSafariViewController` but same issue. I have a [sample iOS app here](https://github.com/basememara/iOS-Password-Autofill-ASWebAuthenticationSession). Any help or experience is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only working and clean solution I've found after a loooong research is **adding a post login page** as suggested [here](https://authguidance.com/2020/02/22/ios-code-sample-overview/). This way the save credentials prompt won't be dissmissed.

Unfortunately I didn't found any solution from the iOS side, it would be really appreciated since in my case I can't change the server side due to project restrictions.

Comment: Also this was another workaround that worked: https://github.com/basememara/iOS-Password-Autofill-ASWebAuthenticationSession/commit/9f8f3cfa39b8d0124c262c3f7f5cd5865ade17e1

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill):

> Password AutoFill recommends credentials only for your app’s
>   associated domain, and the user must authenticate using Face ID or
>   Touch ID before accessing these credentials.

Make sure the app is associated with your domain (`example.com` in your code). This will allow iCloud Keychain to identify the login form and suggest any stored credentials for that domain.

1. Associate your app with the domain, as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains_in_your_app).
2. Add the `html` tags to your login form, as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_an_html_input_element).
3. Make sure the user is properly authenticated on the iOS device before launching the `ASWebAuthenticationSession`.

Comment: This does not work because web credentials only work with native text fields. If we had to do this, it wouldn't work with any 3rd party OAuth service, like Google, GitHub, Facebook, etc logins since they'd have to update their associated files with every consumer of their SDK.